# How to keep multiple windows focused at the same time (on Windows 10)

Tags: windows, multi-touch, window-management

I am working on making a large multi-touch table which is powered by Windows 10. I have the idea that multiple people could work on the table at once, on different windows. The problem is, Windows 10 only allows one windows to be focused at once. This makes it impossible for more than one person to work on it at once, as the focus would keep changing, and it would not work well at all. I was wondering if there is some way to make multiple windows 'focused' at the same time.

Thanks in advance for any help given.

Comment: No, this is impossible. If multiple windows could get the focus, which one would get the input?

Comment: @William: How did you finally solve the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cannot give you a definitive answer on this, but I looked into using several mice and keyboards on windows a while ago, and the main problem was that you could not have several windows focussed at the same time, which messed up keyboard input. I have found no solution to this.
Since in windows 10 touch input is similar to mouse input, your only getaway may be virtualization.

E. G. have each window run by a virtual machine which has been assigned one keyboard and one mouse. This way, every window would respond to input whenever (focussed or not)

As for touch input, I guess you have one single input device, but the virtual machines may be able to read input form the screen while out of focus (I never tried this)